# Why can't you install docker natively in osx?

Tags: macos, docker

I would love to be able to use docker outside of Vagrant in OSX. Right now this is not possible. What are the specific reasons causing it not to be limited for linux installations only?

Comment: Not sure why this is closed - the reason given below doesn't seem to apply, since Docker is 'used primarily for programming' (specifically, it's used as a container mechanism to deploy web apps).

Comment: @mikemaccana, eh? Software *deployment* is on-topic over at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). And that it's about software used "primarily" for software development is not enough to make something topical: That a problem or question (as opposed to the software it's about) should be "unique to software development" is ANDed into the other conditions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Not sure why 'eh' is appropriate: clearly 16 other people think my comment is reasonable. Running Docker on OS X is unique to software development. Very few people would run a non-development Linux workload on OS X, which has no server version anymore. Even if this is more appropriate for ServerFault, it should be moved there rather than closed.

Comment: I know this is years old, but I wanted to chime in and say that this is very very poor moderation.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Docker is just an abstraction & automation layer on top of system-provided containers.

The technical limitation is that OS X does not support [operating system-level virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system-level_virtualization), like [containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC) in Linux or [jails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail) in FreeBSD (even despite the fact that OS X is a half-blood BSD).

But even despite that, Docker aims to provide an easy way to share container images, and to make sure that any Docker image would work on any Docker-compatible system, they had to limit it only to Linux. (That is probably why Docker doesn't support FreeBSD and friends, which do have containers.)

**UPDATE**: you can use projects like [docker-osx](https://github.com/noplay/docker-osx) or [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io) to enjoy Docker on your OS X machine almost seamlessly (both create a Linux virtual machine behind the scenes.)

Comment: This is true until 1.0. At that point, docker will be able to manage non-lxc based containers. One such example would allow docker to run inside of a *chroot* for some types of work.

Comment: The current version of the docker client seems to run fine on OSX, as long as you point it at a running docker daemon somewhere else, e.g. inside a VM. How-to: https://coderwall.com/p/r6ivdq

Comment: Docker now has an officially sanctioned method of running on OSX: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/mac/ but it's running on a VM

Comment: and if you run boot2docker and want to share folders seamlessly, read http://goo.gl/QkeHMS

Comment: still not happy about this and Boot2Docker. they don't even plan to make it run natively on osx. hate having to install a vm for docker (the irony)

Comment: @Claudiu you can't run it natively because OS X does not have Jails or equivalent. From my basic understanding, chroot is far from sufficient. Docker is just a frontend for software virtualization libraries, such as LXC.

Comment: `almost seamlessly`...However disk access is insanely slow thanks to VirtualBox. OSX absolutely needs its own native Docker. boot2docker is not the answer.

Comment: Docker requires an underlying Linux kernel.  No matter how it may appear or what _may_ be possible through 'lxc' etc,, Docker _is_ Linux.  I wish they would make that clear.  
If this were not the case we would have Windows containers for Windows and OSX containers for OSX, and they would run natoively on those operating systems.  On a non-Linux operating system it _always_ uses a VM (running a Linux kernel) underneath.